Что значит предложение "Что нужно вещает? "
Что значит предложение "Что нужно вещает? "

"Говорит то, что нужно?"

От контекста зависит. Наиболее вероятные смыслы:
Говорит именно то, что он него требуют. Пример: "Начальство не переживало, что продавец сдаст их мошеннические схемы. Он что нужно вещает".
Говорит о том, что нужно кому-то. Пример: "Собираясь в экспедицию, члены группы прислушивались к рекомендациям старшего, ибо он бывалый и что нужно вещает".
